# Why controls inside update panels took long to update even website integrated with a CDN network?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, cdn, dynamic

I have a website which written by using ASP.NET. I hosted this website in USA ( Kansas city ) with Quad Core Processor and 8Gb RAM( Dedicated Server: 1GBPS Speed Line). Also my website is running through cloudflare CDN. I am using update panels in my webpages to do asynchronous page request to server.

eg: When user select an item from a dropdown menu getting records that related to selected item.

I access this site from long away from server ( Near to India ). So now the problem is it will took at least 3 to 4 seconds to update my content which are inside update panels.

So According to my knowledge I believe CDN only accelerates static contents of the website. So how about these dynamic data? How major websites like Facebook and Linked solve this problem?

If I run website from local ( my PC ) it is really fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So According to my knowledge I believe CDN only accelerates static contents of the website. So how about these dynamic data?"

CloudFlare only [caches static content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default. If you want to look at accelerating other content, then you could possibly look at using [PageRules to cache other content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) as well.